# Change axis label font for one value only

Tags: python, matplotlib

A particular label on a bar graph is much longer than the other labels, thus I would like to use a "condensed" font on that particular label:

[image: Example graph with long label]

**How might I use an alternative font for only the problematic label?** The machine has the "Ubuntu" font family installed, which has a terrific condensed variant which would be perfect for this case. Applying the condensed variant to all the labels looks terrible, therefore I would prefer to limit it to just the single long line.

The code is not entirely unlike this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib
import pylab

matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'ubuntu'
labels = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Really long label']
values = [5, 3, 4]

ind = pylab.array(range(3))
pyplot.barh(ind, values, 0.5)
pyplot.yticks(range(3), labels)
pyplot.tight_layout()

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Could you split it with newlines? `Notso\nlong\nlabel'`

Comment: @PeterWood: Unfortunately in the "real graph" the labels and bars are too densely packed to add newlines. Otherwise that might have been a good solution. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the `Text` artist used to draw the tick label and directly modify it.  I also changed your code over to use the OO interface (as would be suitable to use in a function) and removed `pylab` (please don't use `pylab`, use `pyplot` and `numpy` directly).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'ubuntu'
labels = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Really long label']
values = [5, 3, 4]

ind = np.array(range(3))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(ind, values, 0.5, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(range(3))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
fig.tight_layout()

txt = ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()[-1]
txt.set_fontstretch('condensed')
txt.set_fontsize(5)  # I also change the font size

plt.draw()
```

I also change the font size as I am not sure that I have the correct fonts installed on my system.  I also added the `align='center'` kwarg to `barh` as I assumed you wanted the labels centered on the bars.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a beautiful answer! I very much appreciate the code review, I have learned quite a lot. Have a great week!

Comment: Regarding the suggestion not to use pylab in favour of using pyplot and numpy directly, why? Do you have a link that I should read on the topic? I find that pylab wraps numpy, matplotlib, and scipy very nicely, but I'm new and naive and would love to learn the right way, which includes learning the "why". Thank you!

Comment: `pylab` is a very messy module that bulk imports various bits of matplotlib and numpy (but not scipy) which was created as an attempt to mimic MATLABs repl api, but completely throws away the idea of namespaces (which are one of the major advantages of python over MATLAB).  A decade ago this made more sense, but now the advice is to use more pythonic patterns.  There is too much documentation floating in the wild to deprecate pylab, but I advocate against it when ever I see it ;)

Comment: I see, that does make sense. Even just importing pylab in the interactive interpreter takes noticeable time. Thank you!